# Undefined is not an object (evaluating'_this.props)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Run on android emulator but **undefined is not an object (evaluating'_this.props)**.

Hello guys, I would like a help to call MainScreen through onpress =>, can someone help me see where I'm going wrong

App.js is my Frist screen and MainScreen is the Second screen

I use App to navigate to Mainscreen.

> **APP.JS**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  View,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Animated,
} from "react-native";
import { CollectionList } from "./src/components/CollectionList";
import { CollectionCreate } from "./src/components/CollectionCreate";
import { MainScreen } from "./MainScreen";
import { firstScreenStack } from "./MainScreen";



function App(props) {
  
  
  const [offset] = useState(new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 0, y: 95 }));
  const [opacity] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));
  
  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.parallel([
      Animated.spring(offset.y, {
        toValue: 0,
        speed: 4,
        bounciness: 20,
      }),
      Animated.timing(opacity, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 550,
      }),
    ]).start();
  }, []);
  props.navigation 
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.background}>
      <View style={styles.containerLogo}>
        <Image source={require("./assets/logoLogin.png")} />
      </View>

      <Animated.View
        style={[
          styles.container,
          {
            opacity: opacity,
            transform: [{ translateY: offset.y }],
          },
        ]}
      >
        <TextInput
          style={styles.imput}
          placeholder="Email"
          autoCorrect={false}
          onChangeText={() => {}}
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.imput}
          placeholder="Senha"
          autoCorrect={false}
          onChangeText={() => {}}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.btAcess}
          onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate(MainScreen)}
          >
          <Text style={styles.btSubText}
         
          >Acessar</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btCreate}>
          <Text style={styles.btPassText}>Criar conta</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Animated.View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  background: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#a4a4a4",
  },

  containerLogo: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
  },

  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    width: "90%",
    paddingBottom: 50,
  },

  imput: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    width: "90%",
    marginBottom: 15,
    color: "#222",
    fontSize: 17,
    borderRadius: 7,
    padding: 10,
  },

  text: {
    color: "#FFF",
  },

  btAcess: {
    backgroundColor: "#00a0cf",
    width: "90%",
    height: 45,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    borderRadius: 7,
  },
  btSubText: {
    color: "#ffff",
    fontSize: 18,
  },

  btCreate: {
    marginTop: 8,
  },
  btPassText: {
    color: "#FFF",
  },
});
export default App;
```

> MainScreen.js

```js
import "react-native-gesture-handler";

import * as React from "react";
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Image, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";

import { CollectionList } from "./src/components/CollectionList";
import { CollectionCreate } from "./src/components/CollectionCreate";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";

import CustomSidebarMenu from "./CustomSidebarMenu";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const NavigationDrawerStructure = (props) => {
  const toggleDrawer = () => {
    props.navigationProps.toggleDrawer();
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleDrawer}>
        <Image
          source={{
            uri:
              "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AboutReact/sampleresource/master/drawerWhite.png",
          }}
          style={{ width: 25, height: 25, marginLeft: 5 }}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default function firstScreenStack({navigation}) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="FirstPage">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="FirstPage"
        component={CollectionList}
        options={{
          title: "Carfix",

          headerLeft: () => (
            <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />
          ),
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#007AFF",
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff",
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "bold",
          },
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function secondScreenStack() {
  return (
    
    <Stack.Navigator
      navigation={navigation}
      initialRouteName="Collection Create"
      screenOptions={{
        headerLeft: () => (
          <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />
        ),
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#007AFF",
        },
        headerTintColor: "#fff",
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: "bold",
        },
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Collection Create"
        component={CollectionCreate}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export function MainScreen (props) {

  return (
      
      <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator 
        drawerContentOptions={{
          activeTintColor: "#007AFF",
          itemStyle: { marginVertical: 1 },
        }}
        
        drawerContent={(props) => <CustomSidebarMenu {...props} />}
        >
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="FirstPage"
          options={{
            drawerLabel: "Carfix",
            drawerIcon: ({ focused, size }) => (
              <Image
              source={require("./assets/homeIcon.png")}
              style={styles.iconStyle}
              />
              ),
            }}
            component={firstScreenStack}
            />
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="SecondPage"
          options={{
            drawerLabel: "Camera",
            drawerIcon: ({ focused, size }) => (
              <Image
              source={require("./assets/cameraIcon.png")}
              style={styles.iconStyle}
              />
              ),
            }}
            component={secondScreenStack}
            />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  sideMenuProfileIcon: {
    resizeMode: "center",
    width: 70,
    height: 70,
    borderRadius: 200 / 2,
    alignSelf: "center",
    marginTop: 100,
  },
  iconStyle: {
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    marginBottom: 4,
    marginLeft: 1,
  },
  customItem: {
    padding: 16,
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginRight: 5,
  },
  textSideBar: {
    marginTop: 9,
  },
});
```

Comment: `onPress={() => this.props.navigation(MainScreen)}`?? this is a functional component, remove the this

Comment: New error apper, props.navigation is not a function. (in 'props.navigation(_Mainscreen.default)','props.navigation' is undefined)

Answer (score 1):

On your `app.js` component, you do `this.props.navigation...`. You can't access to the component props like that.

It is a functional component so if you want to access to the props object,

```js
function App(props) {
  ...
  props.navigation...
}
```

Comment: I make the changes and the Exception stay. undefined is not an object (evaluating'_this.props.navigation')

Comment: function App(props) {
  
  const [offset] = useState(new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 0, y: 95 }));
  const [opacity] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));

Comment: export default function MainScreen (props) {
  
  return (
      <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator 
        drawerContentOptions={{
          activeTintColor: "#007AFF",
          itemStyle: { marginVertical: 1 },
        }}

Comment: <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.btAcess}
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation(MainScreen)}
          >

Comment: You still have the `this.`

Comment: You have to remove it

Comment: New error apper, props.navigation is not a function. (in 'props.navigation(_Mainscreen.default)','props.navigation' is undefined)

Comment: You should first check the react-navigation documentation and some ReactJS basics. The navigation props is not a function but an object. To navigate to another screen, you should do `props.navigation.navigate("YourScreenName");`

Comment: I'm not going to guess your error message.

Comment: You need to edit your post and add the new code. Did I need to tell you that everytime lool

Comment: Ok so if you want to use the navigate function `props.navigation.navigate("YourScreenName")` not `props.navigation.navigate(YourScreenComponent)` did you see the difference ? it is a string param with the name of your screen not the component

Comment: You can check the react-navigation docs if you need more info https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating#navigating-to-a-new-screen

Comment: Make the change, and still error, "undefined is not an object(evaluating'props.navigation.navigate')

Comment: Ok i'm going to reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating#navigating-to-a-new-screen

Comment: I read the whole document and I can't find the problems, I remade it according to the script, however it still gives me the same problem, that the function is not an object when I call onPress